# Boundaries of three distinct sets is equal to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology

Give three distinct subsets $A, B, C$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $ \partial A = \partial B = \partial C = \mathbb Z$.

I considered the following subsets :

1. $A = \mathbb Z$. $\partial A = \overline A \backslash \mathring{A}$. $\overline A = A = \mathbb Z$ and $\mathring A = \emptyset$. Hence, $\partial A = \mathbb Z$.
2. $B = \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Z$. Then $\partial B = \overline B \backslash \mathring B = \mathbb R \backslash (\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z$.
3. For the third set $C$, I can't think of any thing straightforward. I defined sequence of sets $C_n = \{ \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb Z} (i - \frac{1}{n},i) \cup (i, i + \frac{1}{n}) $. Then if $C = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}C_n$, then $\partial C = \mathbb Z $.

However, $C$ doesn't seem all that different from the set of integers. It's just defined as a sequence. Is there a better way to think about the third set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last set is empty if the limit is to be understood as the intersection of all the $C_n$. I don't see how this could lead to something different from the empty set or ${\bf Z}$ even if you change the meaning of your limit.

Now why not trying something like $[0,1]\cup {\bf Z}$?

Comment: I feel like a dum-dum now. That was insanely easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the fact that intervals have two ends.  Use your $A$, then let $B=\cup_{n \in \Bbb Z} (2n,2n+1)$ and $C=\cup_{n \in \Bbb Z} (2n+1,2n+2
)$

Answer (score 1):

It seems one can quite easily characterize all subsets $X ⊆ ℝ$ having $ℤ$ as boundary. Every such set is of the form $A ∪ ⋃_{k ∈ B} (k, k + 1)$ for $A, B ⊆ ℤ$. But not all of them work. They are subject to the following constraint: if both $(k - 1, k)$, $(k, k + 1)$ are contained in $X$, then $k ∉ X$, and if none of them is contained in $X$, then $k ∈ X$. (If just one of them is contained, you are free to choose what to do with $k$.)